# Формат даты при Select в ActiveRecord

Tags: php, sql, yii2, activerecord

В модели делаю запрос в базу, получаю все данные что нужно и дату в формате **2016-10-02 09:45:25+03**.

 $query = (new \yii\db\Query())->
                select('cd.date day,
                c.host_id, cd.customer_id')
            ->from('customer_download cd')
            ->leftJoin('customer c', '"c"."id" = "cd"."customer_id"')

Но мне нужно эту дате привести к виду **2016-10-02 09:45:25**. В запросе я делал это так: 

to_char(cd.date,  'YYYY-MM-dd HH24:MI') as day

Но когда я вставляю этот код в первый запрос to_char(cd.date,  'YYYY-MM-dd HH24:MI') day, то получаю ошибку **syntax error at or near "AS"**
Как правильно это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть решение:
**1. Нужно читать документацию.**
2. Я использую new \yii\db\Query(), значит нужно читать 
3. Там сказано: *Кроме имён столбцов, вы можете также использовать SQL выражения. Вы должны использовать формат массива для использования выражений, которые содержат запятые для предотвращения некорректного автоматического экранирования*

Решение:

$query = (new \yii\db\Query())->
                select(["to_char(cd.date,  'YYYY-MM-dd HH24:MI') as day",
                "c.host_id", "cd.customer_id"])
            ->from('customer_download cd')
            ->leftJoin('customer c', '"c"."id" = "cd"."customer_id"')